# Inserting "basemap" into ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I want to model a 3D scene, showing layers floating above a flat map. Currently, I am able to show the floating layers, but I cannot add the bottommost map layer. I just want to add a "basemap", like ArcMap allows, but none of the files seem to be compatible. Just saving a basemap as a lyr file in ArcMap and importing it in ArcScene does not work, and raster images obtained from the Internet do not line up properly when added to the scene.

I know that the online basemaps that are available in ArcMap do not work in ArcScene. I was wondering if there was any way to add a simple, flat map to a scene in ArcScene?

The illustration below illustrates what I want as my final product:

[image: The intended final product]

Comment: I suppose you could clip/export the basemap layer to a raster covering your area of interest. Side note, basemap layers DO work in ArcGlobe, but are [confirmed](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q80000012v000000) to not work in ArcScene.

Comment: @blah238 I have actually tried exporting the portion of the map I need to a JPEG and TIFF, but neither of them appear in the right location, nor appear in the right size in ArcScene. I haven't used the "clip" tool, but just kept the part of the map I needed in the view window. This seems to clip it automatically, but maybe that is where I am wrong... And I know ArcGlobe can use basemaps, but I really need the camera rotation flexibility that ArcScene offers.

Comment: I suppose there is ArcGlobe for having such a base layer..

Answer (score 3):

- Add basemap to ArcMap
- Export to jpeg or tiff
- Add exported jpeg / tiff to ArcMap
- **Georeference** the exported image
- **Update Georeferencing!**
- Add georeferenced image to ArcScene
- Set Base Heigt to constant elevation or float on surface (DEM, TIN)

Comment: I don't think georeferencing should be necessary, the export or clip functions should maintain the georeferencing automatically.

Comment: Good point.  Should work, but only while in DATA VIEW. Options to export georeferencing info are not available when in Layout View.